# Which are the right configurations in the Markov chain of a Hamiltonian Monte Carlo algorithm?

Tags: computational-physics, monte-carlo, molecular-dynamics

I have a question about the *Markov Chain Hamiltonian Monte Carlo* (MCHMC).
*Hamiltonian Monte Carlo* is known as *Hybrid Monte Carlo* too. I'll describe the steps of the algorithm.

1. We have at the beginning a coordinates configuration {$q_i$} and generate momenta configuration {$p_i$} from a gaussian distribution at the desired temperature $T$.

   $i$ run over the *degrees of freedom* of the system. So we initially have the configuration {$q_i, p_i$}. This is **the first configuration in our Markov chain**
2. We make $n$ leapfrog steps and obtain the configuration {$q'_i, p'_i$}
3. We accept or reject this last configuration using a *Metropolis* test

Now we continue with an example. Suppose this last configuration is rejected. Then we keep the old configuration {$q_i,p_i$} (**first question: this is the second configuration of our Markov chain, right?**) and generate (for the second time) a new {$p''_i$} set of momenta gaussian distributed. So we now have the configuration {$q_i, p''_i$}.

Now we make other $n$ leapfrog steps and arrive at the configuration {$q''_i, p'''_i$}. **Second question: if Metropolis rejects it, the third configuration of our Markov chain will be** {$q_i, p_i$} **or** {$q_i, p''_i$}**?**.

Now, instead, we suppose *Metropolis* accepts {$q''_i, p'''_i$}, and we generate a new gaussian set {$p^{IV}_i$}. So we now have the configuration {$q'', p^{IV}_i$} and then continue from it with leapfrog. **The last question is: which is the third configuration of our Markov chain,** {$q''_i, p'''_i$} **or** {$q''_i, p^{IV}_i$}**?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm for perfoming a single HMC step is as follows:

**Input:** Some initial configuration $\vec{y}_i$ and momentum $\vec{p}_i$.
**Output:** Next configuration $\vec{y}_{i+1}$ and momentum $\vec{p}_{i+1}$

1. Draw a random momentum $\vec{p}_*$ from a Gaussian distribution.
2. Numerically solve Hamilton's equations of motion for some time (i.e., perform some Leapfrog steps) with initial conditions $(\vec{y}_i, \vec{p}_*)$. The end point of the trajectory is denoted by $(\vec{y}_c, \vec{p}_c)$.
3. Compute the acceptance probability $\rho_i \in [0,1]$ of the proposal / candidate $(\vec{y}_c, \vec{p}_c)$: $$\rho_i = \min\{\exp\left( - \beta \left( \mathcal{H}(\vec{y}_c, \vec{p}_c) - \mathcal{H}(\vec{y}_i, \vec{p}_i) \right) \right), 1\}.$$
   Here, $\mathcal{H}$ denotes the Hamiltonian and $\beta > 0$ is the inverse temperature.
4. Draw a random number $\alpha_i \sim U([0,1])$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and set $$(\vec{y}_{i+1}, \vec{p}_{i+1}) = \begin{cases} (\vec{y}_c, \vec{p}_c) & \text{if } \alpha_i \leq \rho_i, \\ (\vec{y}_i, \vec{p}_i) & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Now, to answer your questions (and to give some additional remarks):

- Usually, the degrees of freedom are not treated separately. This is especially problematic if the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$ does not decompose into multiplicative factors for each DOF. In the algorithm above, the full state $\vec{y}$ is drawn (i.e., all DOFs are drawn simultaneously).
- If a proposal is rejected, the initial state is taken ($\vec{y}_{i+1} = \vec{y}_i$).
- If two proposals are rejected in a row, the chain is still in the original state ($\vec{y}_{i+1} = \vec{y}_i$ and $\vec{y}_{i+2} = \vec{y}_{i+1}$, which implies $\vec{y}_{i+2} = \vec{y}_i$).